# Is there any way to copy magento block?

Tags: magento2

Is there any way to copy search-block in magento2?

I need to place it on completely different place on mobile resolution, but in order to so, i guess i need to copy it into another container. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you're referring to the `top.search` block defined in `vendor/magento/module-search/view/frontend/layout/default.xml`

You can add another block in your custom layout, for example:

```xml
...
<referenceContainer name="yourContainer">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" 
        name="top.search.mobile" as="topSearchMobile"
        template="Magento_Search::form.mini.mobile.phtml" />
</referenceContainer>
...
```

Just remember to change the `name` and `as` attributes.

Then if you look at the original template file `form.mini.phtml` you will notice that there are some ids to change since the `quickSearch` js component relies on them.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->getBlock('top.search')->toHtml(); ?>
```